# Importing products straight to Magento's mysql database

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I have my own database with product information. I want to upload these products straight to Magento's mySQL database. I tried investigating database structure and it's extremely confusing. So far what I've figured out is that they store product information across many different and therefore understanding every table and how it all comes together seems impossible. Is there any way to import products to magento without making direct sql queries to many different tables ? Or perhaps there's some other way to import products to magento programatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page) is based on importing product, categories  through direct SQL queries. You should have a look there. More [here](http://www.phpro.be/news/magmi-magento-mass-importer). Or you can google it to find more about Magmi Project